# pyproj.database and pyproj.aoi import failed

Tags: python, python-import, pyproj

I have installed the pyproj.2.6.1 version, and I am using the python3.8.8; I can't correctly import the module   **query_utm_crs_info** from **pyproj** package.

Here below the code :

```
from pyproj import Proj,  Transformer, CRS
from pyproj.database import query_utm_crs_info

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.database'
```

Similar problem with  AreaOfInterest

```
from pyproj.aoi import AreaOfInterest
```

and I received this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.aoi'
```

However, if I change it in to

```
from pyproj.transformer import AreaOfInterest
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/database.html#pyproj.database.query_crs_info

query_crs_info was added in pyproj 3.